# How do I flip button colors on hover?

Tags: button, hover

I have a white button with green text. How do I flip the colors on hover to a green button with white text in my span?

```
<a class="fusion-button button-flat button-round button-large button-custom button-1 button" target="_self" href="http://greenhousebuilders.co/about">
<span class="fusion-button-text">learn more</span>
</a>
```

The code looks like this with a span inside the  tag. It's wordpress, so I can't change the html, just the css. I want the span color to change when the a is hovered over. Is this possible? Right now I can only get the span color to change when the span is hovered over.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.fusion-button { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 3px;
  color: green;
}


a:hover { background: green; }
a:hover span { color: white }
```

```html
<a class="fusion-button button-flat button-round button-large button-custom button-1 button" target="_self" href="http://greenhousebuilders.co/about">
<span class="fusion-button-text">learn more</span>
</a>
```